# How to create a line space in a Rails partial view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, line, partial

In my `index.html.erb` view, I have the following `render` to display each and every flight (without doing a `.each`:

```
<%= render @flights %>
```

However, as I have the flights partial written, all the flights are listed side-by-side. What I want is one flight listed per line. How do I create a line space after each flight?

```
<%= radio_button_tag :flight_id, flight.id %>
<%= flight.id %>
<%= flight.date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")  %>
<%= flight.date.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p') %>
<%= flight.from_airport.code %>
<%= flight.to_airport.code %>
<%= distance_of_time_in_words(flight.duration) %>
```

Comment: You can do with `tables`,but you have to `loop` through the records with `each`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use tables?

```
<table>
  <%= render @flights %>
</table>
```

and in your partial write

```
<tr>
  <td><%= radio_button_tag :flight_id, flight.id %></td>
  <td><%= flight.id %></td>
  <td><%= flight.date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")  %></td>
  <td><%= flight.date.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p') %></td>
  <td><%= flight.from_airport.code %></td>
  <td><%= flight.to_airport.code %></td>
  <td><%= distance_of_time_in_words(flight.duration) %></td>
</tr>
```

Arrgghhhh so much typing, and so error-prone. 
For educational purposes, why not use [haml](http://haml.info/)?

```
%table
  = render @flights
```

in your partial:

```
%tr
  %td= radio_button_tag :flight_id, flight.id 
  %td= flight.id 
  %td= flight.date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")  
  %td= flight.date.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p') 
  %td= flight.from_airport.code 
  %td= flight.to_airport.code 
  %td= distance_of_time_in_words(flight.duration)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<br/>` html tag in the end of your partial.

```
<%= radio_button_tag :flight_id, flight.id %>
<%= flight.id %>
<%= flight.date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")  %>
<%= flight.date.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p') %>
<%= flight.from_airport.code %>
<%= flight.to_airport.code %>
<%= distance_of_time_in_words(flight.duration) %>
<br/>
```